# Image Recognition using Tensorflow on s390x (Tutorial Example)

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I've installed the Tensorflow package and complied it from source for IBM s390x architecture.  The image recognition classify_image.py sample as described in the tutorial throws an error as shown below:

Run command:

```
python ./classify_image.py --model_dir=/data/shared/myprojects/tensorflow/models/models-master/tutorials/image/imagenet --image_file=/data/shared/myprojects/keras/images/claude_profile.jpg
```

Error message:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 659, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    raise ValueError(err.message)
ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 1041082757314414592 elements to shape [16777216,524288] (8796093022208 elements) for 'pool_3/_reshape' (op: 'Reshape') with input shapes: [1,22546423,22546423,2048], [2] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [16777216,524288].
```

Version:

```
python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.VERSION
'1.3.1'
>>>
```

A possible error cause is an incompatibility of endianness as the trained model likely is stored in a little endian notation while the CPU works in a  big endian mode. Is there an easy way to configure a byte swapping that changes the endianness of the input data? Other Tensorflow samples, without image processing routines execute OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1041082757314414592 sounds more like an overflow / underflow than endianness issue. If you don't try to load an example but try to run one from scratch do you also see issues?

Comment: The inception model is part of the TensorFlow distribution. I've done a bazel build according to the instructions here [ https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining ] 

The retrain step  caused exactly the same run-time error when loading the binary model file name classify_image_graph_def.pb: 
ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 1041082757314414592 elements to shape [16777216,524288] (8796093022208 elements) for 'pool_3/_reshape' (op: 'Reshape') with input shapes: [1,22546423,22546423,2048], [2] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [16777216,524288].

Comment: Can you file a bug on github?

Comment: Thanks for the support. I've filed a bug under Github #2485. Our community support team is checking the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be happening because the inception model being a pre-trained model on a Little Endian machine, will have issues while loading on Big Endian(s390x). Also any graph (*eg. classify_image_graph_def.pb*) will store values like size in one format, which gives unexpected results when read in the other.

As far as I know there is no tool available yet to convert any saved model to be compatible on big endian.

So for now, on big endian, we need to train our nodes from scratch.